# Django does not find static files which are not tied to specific apps

Tags: django

I want to put the static files in the folder outside any apps. This is the file structure.

```
     mysite
       |---assets
             |---css
             |---js
             |---images   
       |---companyinfo 
             |---views.py
             |---models.py
             |---templates
                     |---index.html
                     |---recruit.html
             |--- ....
       |---mysite
             |---urls.py
             |---settings.py
             |--- ....
       |---manage.py 
       |--- ....
```

settings.py looks like the following.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'  
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
]
```

This is how I call the static files in the template files,

```
 <link href="assets/css/theme-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

urls.py under mysite folder looks like the following. I did not define a urls.py under companyinfo folder.

```
from companyinfo import views as civiews

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', civiews.index, name='index'),
url(r'^recruit/$', civiews.recruit, name='recruit'),
]
```

views.py is just two functions that render the html pages. The urls for the static files are the same in the two html pages.
The problem is the index page loads well with all the css and js files, but the recruit page does not find those files. What might the problem be? I'm using Django1.10.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's strange. Show, please, how do you call the static files from within your templates.

Comment: Thanks. I have added how I call the static files in the templates.

Comment: If my answer helped you accept it, please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Comment: Jusy for your information, in StackOverflow the `upvote` action is different from the `accept` one! If, the below answer helped you, you should click on the tick icon below. Although, you can upvote + accept at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this:

`<link href="assets/css/theme-style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to this:

`<link href="{% url 'css/theme-style.css %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Thank you! It works. Another related question is one of my js files also has a hard coded path:  `var PLUGINS_LOCALPATH = './assets/plugins/';`
How can I change it to a similar path as in the template file?

Comment: You can't! The only solution is to create a js object in your main HTML, pass there the URL and then use it in the following js files. But for questions like that you should better create a separate one!